# Phrase - "any old holidays"

Tags: frase

I want to say "they were not any old holidays". I read the post  [What is the rule for cualquier, cualquiera, and cualesquiera?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2487/what-is-the-rule-for-cualquier-cualquiera-and-cualesquiera)

I am wondering then is it: "no fueron unas vacaciones cualesquiera" or would it be better to just say "normales"?

Thanks

Comment: We need context, or we can't properly translate it, "cualesquiera" sounds to me like a manual or math book. No fueron las típicas vacaciones. En realidad no hubo vacaciones.

Comment: I guess I want to say, they are holidays that are out of the ordinary, not the usual or typical holiday. I am writing about doing the Camio in Santiago de Compostela.

Comment: I think maybe wimi has answered my question well below but if anyone else has anything to add I am happy too.

Comment: You can also use 'más' in this sense. 'No fueron unas vacaciones más'. The problem with 'cualesquiera' is that the plural form is mostly used in formal language, so a lot of people would tend to say 'no fueron unas vacaciones cualquiera', but this is frowned upon as a mistake as wimi points out below.

Comment: Thanks. I always wondered what " más " meant in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, and there are examples of both in the press or in promotional texts:

- [No son unas vacaciones cualesquiera](http://rinconsolidario.diariodenavarra.es/2012/06/no-son-unas-vacaciones-cualesquiera.html)
- [No son unas vacaciones normales](https://www.facebook.com/MAPFREsv/posts/2618099845119876)

For me, "no son unas vacaciones cualesquiera" has a slightly more emphatic meaning (i.e., they are *really* special holidays), but the difference is very small.

The use of *cualquiera* in singular form in this context is a common mistake according to [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/cualquiera):

> A menudo se utiliza erróneamente la forma del singular para el plural:❌«*No se debe, cualquiera que sean las circunstancias, admitir que se denigre el nivel del debate*» (*DYucatán* [Méx.] 12.9.96)